# internal javascript clear function

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript objects that are used to replicate data objects.  They are filled in via onclick events, and I want to clear them out after a save event.

For example,

```
var currentStrategy = {
  id : "",
  label : "",
  dueDate : "",
  comments = [],

  save : saveStrategyHandler,
  clear : function() {
    //how do I clear the fields above in here?
  }
}
```

I've tried

```
function(){
  id = "";
  label = "";
  dueDate = "";
  comments = [];
}
```

and

```
function(){
  currentStrategy = {};
}
```

but neither work.

Comment: Assign to the *properties* of your object, not to some variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following. Instance properties need a `this`.

```
var currentStrategy = {
  id : "",
  label : "",
  dueDate : "",
  comments = [],

  save : saveStrategyHandler,
  clear : function() {
    this.id = "";
    this.label = "";
    this.dueDate = "";
    this.comments = [];
  }
}
```